# Portable Way to Convert MIDI to a Soundfile With a Custom Soundfont?

Tags: audio, portable, midi

Yes, I know this question exists: https://superuser.com/questions/1011409/how-do-i-export-a-midi-to-a-sound-file-without-playing-it-in-realtime

But none of the answers I found on there were of any help.

=====

Are there any tools that can convert a MIDI file to a WAV file with the option to use other Soundfonts?

I have not had any success with Winamp Plug-ins or Timidity++. I have been searching the the internet for a simple and free tool to do the job (it can't possibly be that difficult).

Preferred (in order of priority):

1. Free
2. Portable (As mentioned before)
3. Can be used with command-line
4. Maybe other options such as format to output to or bit-rate.

Comment: try anvil studio

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic and should not really be answered.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Ok, maybe I should get this question moved to stack exchange music.

Comment: @Fennekin I managed to get a portable version of anvil studio with universal extractor, I may post my steps on how I did that as an answer. I will get back once I try to figure out how to render a midi to a soundfile.

Comment: Use file->export mixed audio in anvil studio

Comment: @Fennekin unfortunately, that records in real-time. I've heard of fluidsynth and maniac tools, but maniac tools is not free and I was unable to extract any sort of exe from the fluidsynth1 installer

Comment: are you trying to do batch converting?

Comment: Both [fluidsynth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762063/convert-midi-file-to-wav-using-fluidsynth-on-os-x) and [Timidity](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/timidity#Convert_files) can do this. What was your problem when you tried it?

Comment: @CL. It gave me `timidity.exe: Can't read any configuration file.`. I haven't found a portable version of fluidsynth yet.

Comment: How exactly to get them to work on your OS would be a different question.

Comment: @DavidPostill I was wondering if I could get my question migrated, or if I have to delete it (which is bad according to SE) and just repost it on softwarerecs

Comment: Flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it (be specific about where you want it moved to).

Comment: @DavidPostill Alright, I just did that, now we wait.